# seek on flowplayer is not right

Tags: time, flowplayer, seek

I'm trying to seek video with no steaming.

this is my page:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>
<title>Flowplayer test</title>
</head><body>

<a style="display:block;width:640px;height:360px" id="player"></a>

<script>
flowplayer("player","flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf",{
    clip: {url:'sp/gailun640x360.mp4'}});

function vgoto(val) {$f(0).seek(val);}
</script>

<a href="javascript:vgoto(0);">0s</a>
<a href="javascript:vgoto(10);">10s</a>
<a href="javascript:vgoto(20);">20s</a>
<a href="javascript:vgoto(30);">30s</a>
<a href="javascript:vgoto(40);">40s</a>
...
<a href="javascript:vgoto(100);">100s</a>

</body></html>
```

When I click "10s" and seek video to 10s, video time become 7.04s,

then I seek to 20s, it become 17.04s,

and so on, like:

```
30s  -> 20.08

40s  -> 30.08

50s  -> 40.08

60s  -> 56.52

70s  -> 66.52

80s  -> 76.52

90s  -> 86.52

100s -> 90.92
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that flowplayer can seek to keyframes only so in order to be able to seek to any second you need to have keyframe for every second. Most probably that means that you need to recode videos when they are uploaded using ffmpeg configured to force keyframes every second.

Comment: I use MP4 video, it didn't work, but flv video is fine.

Comment: Are you sure you've properly re-coded it with keyframes every second? Note that each file may have different frame rate per second.

Comment: I don't know how to recode it with keyframes every second. I tried `-intra` option, but this video can not be played until it load complete.

Comment: Something like `-force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced)` should do it.

Comment: Thank you, but recode with `-force_key_frames` or something else make the video unplayable until it load completely.